# Bootstrap Modal in Firefox not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been creating my site in bootstrap and I have come across a weird problem, when I hit a button that has this in it

```
<form action="javascript:$('#modal .modalbody').load('/controllers/forums/create_topic_modal.php?id='.$forumName['id'].'',function(e){$('#modal').modal('show');});">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" value="Create New Post" />
</form>
```

all I get in firefox is a browser page that says `[object Object]` and the URL says

```
javascript:$('#modal .modal-body').load('/controllers/forums/create_topic_modal.php?id=1',function(e){$('#modal').modal('show');});
```

Any idea whats happening? Works fine in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `onsubmit` attribute (fires when a form is submitted).

If you add `return false;` at the end of `onsubmit`, the form will not trigger a basic behavior (eq. get request/"page refresh").

```
<form onsubmit="$('#modal .modalbody').load('/controllers/forums/create_topic_modal.php?id='.$forumName['id'].'',function(e){$('#modal').modal('show');}); return false;">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" value="Create New Post" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did fix one, I will try the return false on some more and let you know! Worked on my links as well, just had to add, onClick...thanks again, sorry for the dumb question.